# forking a process seems to eat up certain lines of code - Objective-C

Tags: c, objective-c, fork, parent-child

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
- (IBAction)convert:(id)sender
{
    /* these two lines are ignored */
    [textbox setStringValue:@"converting"];
    [convertButton setEnabled:NO];

        pid_t pid;
        if((pid=fork())==-1)
        {
            [log setStringValue:@"couldn't fork a new process."];
            converting = 0;
        [convertButton setEnabled:YES];
            return;
        }else if (pid==0)
        {
            //this is the child
            sleep(2);
            exit(0);
        }else{
            int status;
            waitpid(pid,&status,0);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a pretty basic fork() call. The problem is, the two lines at the very top (marked with a comment) are ignored...they don't seem to execute until *after* the forked child exits. Why?

**Edit**: And what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You really *really* **really** don't want to call `fork()` in a Cocoa application.   There are about a zillion different gotchas when doing so, mostly related to how various resources like mach ports and other system binding infrastructure survives across the `fork()` boundary.  Threads cause all kinds of hell, too.

Use `NSTask` instead.  While it effectively does `fork()`/`exec()` internally, it does so with considerable care to make sure it is done correctly.

Comment: This was exactly it. For anyone who is interested, I've posted as an answer the code that I used.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps because your code must return to the main event loop before the GUI can change state? Or, a slight variation, because the thread that runs the GUI is blocked while your code is doing a kernel-level wait()?

Comment: That sounds very likely...do you know of any solutions?

Comment: The solution is to not block.  The better solution is to not use `fork()` at all.  Forking a GUI level process is exceedingly difficult to do correctly.  Use `NSTask`;  my answer provides more details as to why.

Comment: Excellent. I figured someone who knew the API would come along sooner or later...

Answer (score 1):

bbum got this exactly right. Here's the code I ended up using:

```
- (IBAction)convert:(id)sender
{
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/local/bin/lame"];

    NSArray *arguments;
    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: file,outputFile, nil];
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(taskFinished:) name:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification object:task];

    [task launch];  
}
- (void) taskFinished:(NSNotification *)note {
    // code here executes after process finishes    
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped.  FYI: You are blocking the Main Event Loop in that code;  i.e. the UI won't update until the subprocess exits. No big deal if intended or if the subprocess executes for an exceedingly short period of time....

Comment: @bbum: yep, I got told that in another question :) Edited to reflect a better solution from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817726/ignoring-user-input-while-waiting-for-a-task-objective-c